# How to plot a polar pie chart in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to plot a polar pie chart as shown in the image using d3 js. i searched a lot and tried couple of things on chatgpt but still not getting what i want

Hers is the image
[image]

```
this is the code, its completely wrong but still adding



<script>
    // Sample data for two tools, each containing five features
    const data = [
        {
            tool: "Tool 1",
            features: [
                { name: "Feature 1", value: 1.2, color: "#FF0000" },
                { name: "Feature 2", value: 2.3, color: "#00FF00" },
                { name: "Feature 3", value: 3.4, color: "#FFFF00" },
                { name: "Feature 4", value: 0.8, color: "#0000FF" },
                { name: "Feature 5", value: 2.1, color: "#FFA500" }
            ]
        },
        {
            tool: "Tool 2",
            features: [
                { name: "Feature 1", value: 0.9, color: "#FF0000" },
                { name: "Feature 2", value: 2.8, color: "#00FF00" },
                { name: "Feature 3", value: 2.0, color: "#FFFF00" },
                { name: "Feature 4", value: 1.5, color: "#0000FF" },
                { name: "Feature 5", value: 1.7, color: "#FFA500" }
            ]
        }
    ];

    // Set up the dimensions of the SVG container
    const width = 400;
    const height = 400;
    const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    // Create an SVG element
    const svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);

    // Create a function to generate pie-like segments for the features
    const pie = d3.pie()
        .sort(null) // Disable sorting for features
        .value(d => d.value);

    // Calculate the overall maximum feature value across all tools
    const overallMaxValue = d3.max(data, d => d3.max(d.features, f => f.value));

    // Create a function to generate the pie path for the features
    const arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(d => radius * (d.data.value / overallMaxValue)); // Adjust outer radius based on feature value

    // Add a line to separate the two tools
    svg.append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", -radius)
        .attr("x2", 0)
        .attr("y2", radius)
        .attr("stroke", "darkgray") // Dark gray color
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);

    // Add individual pies for each feature within each tool's section
    const toolSections = svg.selectAll(".tool-section")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "tool-section")
        .attr("transform", (d, i) => `rotate(${i * (180 / data.length)})`); // Rotate each big slice

    const featureSlices = toolSections.selectAll(".feature-slice")
        .data(d => pie(d.features))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "feature-slice")
        .attr("transform", (d, i) => `rotate(${i * (360 / data.length)})`); // Rotate each feature slice within the big slice

    featureSlices
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill", d => d.data.color) // Assign the specified color
        .attr("stroke", "white") // Add a white stroke for feature pies
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);

</script>
```

and it ended up looking like this. i tried a lot of things but not getting what i wanted. the graph should look like above one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Data visualisations are easier if you get the data in the right format to start with, that avoids awkward fixes etc in the vis code itself. So here I've split the data by feature then tool rather than the other way round since the diagram appears to be going for features split by tools. That removes awkward rotations for the individual slices at least.

```
[
  {
    "feature": "Feature 1",
    "tools": [
      {
        "name": "Tool 1",
        "value": 1.2,
        "color": "#ffA500"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tool 2",
        "value": 0.9,
        "color": "#0000ff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "feature": "Feature 2",
    "tools": [
      {
        "name": "Tool 1",
        "value": 2.3,
        "color": "#ffA500"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tool 2",
        "value": 2.8,
        "color": "#0000ff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "feature": "Feature 3",
    "tools": [
      {
        "name": "Tool 1",
        "value": 3.4,
        "color": "#ffA500"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tool 2",
        "value": 2,
        "color": "#0000ff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "feature": "Feature 4",
    "tools": [
      {
        "name": "Tool 1",
        "value": 0.8,
        "color": "#ffA500"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tool 2",
        "value": 1.5,
        "color": "#0000ff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "feature": "Feature 5",
    "tools": [
      {
        "name": "Tool 1",
        "value": 2.1,
        "color": "#ffA500"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tool 2",
        "value": 1.7,
        "color": "#0000ff"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Beyond that, you need to set each 'pie' using endAngle to be only (1/n) circumference otherwise they all take the full circle.

If you could figure out how to sneak an index into that pie construct you could get rid of the transform rotation on the pies by shuffling along startangle/endangle accordingly - you had that original calc working with 180 rather than 360 degrees too

```js
// Sample data for two tools, each containing five features
    const data = [
        {
            tool: "Tool 1",
            features: [
                { name: "Feature 1", value: 1.2, color: "#FF0000" },
                { name: "Feature 2", value: 2.3, color: "#00FF00" },
                { name: "Feature 3", value: 3.4, color: "#FFFF00" },
                { name: "Feature 4", value: 0.8, color: "#0000FF" },
                { name: "Feature 5", value: 2.1, color: "#FFA500" }
            ]
        },
        {
            tool: "Tool 2",
            features: [
                { name: "Feature 1", value: 0.9, color: "#FF0000" },
                { name: "Feature 2", value: 2.8, color: "#00FF00" },
                { name: "Feature 3", value: 2.0, color: "#FFFF00" },
                { name: "Feature 4", value: 1.5, color: "#0000FF" },
                { name: "Feature 5", value: 1.7, color: "#FFA500" }
            ]
        }
    ];
    
    // Probably more efficient way to do this but does the job
    // Flip the grouping above, feature--> tool rather than tool --> feature
    // and colour by tool
    tools = data.map((d) => d.tool);
    features = data[0].features.map ((d) => d.name);
    wrangledData = features.map ((feature) => {
      groupToolByFeature = tools.map ((tool, toolIndex) => {
        toolData = data.filter((d) => d.tool === tool)[0].features;
        datum = toolData.filter ((dd) => dd.name == feature)[0];
        datum.name = tool; // swap for toolname
        datum.color = ["#ffA500", "#0000ff"][toolIndex]; // set color by tool
        return datum;
      });
      return {feature: feature, tools: groupToolByFeature};
    });

    // Set up the dimensions of the SVG container
    const width = 400;
    const height = 400;
    const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    // Create an SVG element
    const svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);

  
 
    // Create a function to generate pie-like segments for the features
    const pie = d3.pie()
        .startAngle (0)
        // endAngle = full circle divided by number of features (in radians)
        .endAngle (2 * Math.PI / wrangledData.length)
        .sort(null) // Disable sorting for features
        .value(d => d.value);

    // Calculate the overall maximum feature value across all tools
    const overallMaxValue = d3.max(wrangledData, d => d3.max(d.tools, f => f.value));
    // Create a function to generate the pie path for the features
    const arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(d => radius * (d.data.value / overallMaxValue)); // Adjust outer radius based on feature value

    // Add a line to separate the two tools
    svg.append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", -radius)
        .attr("x2", 0)
        .attr("y2", radius)
        .attr("stroke", "darkgray") // Dark gray color
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);

    // Add individual pies for each feature
    const featureSections = svg.selectAll(".feature-section")
        .data(wrangledData)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "feature-section")
        .attr("transform", (d, i) => `rotate(${i * (360 / wrangledData.length)})`); // Rotate each big slice

    const toolSlices = featureSections.selectAll(".tool-slice")
        .data(d => pie(d.tools))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "tool-slice");

    toolSlices
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill", d => d.data.color) // Assign the specified color
        .attr("stroke", "white") // Add a white stroke for feature pies
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="chart" height="600" width="600"><svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what i was looking for was Tool 1 should have 5 slices which are its features and Tool2 should have 5 slices which are its features. Like in the first image Team play has two slices green and purple. In my case Team play can be considered the tool name and the slices as its features. Also need the circular coordinates

Comment: If all you want to do is that, then add the endAngle/startAngle to your pie definition, remove the rotate on featureSlice and change the rotate function on toolSections to divide into 360 rather than 180

However what you'll have then is the two tools separated into different halves of the full circle. I think if you want to compare the features you'll want it like that initial diagram - there the teams are tools and the attributes (penalties / free kicks etc) are the features